# Using stative verb "want" in progressive

Tags: continuous-aspect, present-progressive, stative-verbs

Some days ago I found an interesting question.

As I know we can use some stative verbs in continuos with a difference in meaning. There are two sentences:

> 1. We'd been wanting to go to New Zealand for years, so sixtieth birthday was a good excuse
> 2. We're wanting to buy a new TV, but we are not sure what to get

There was an explanation: We can use a continuous form of "want" if we have ***ongoing*** or ***repeated process***; ***indirectness*** or ***politeness***. Is it really acceptable?

P.S.: I am not a native speaker

Comment: Of course, just put negative marks. More "-" without explaining why

Comment: Or everyone consider this question stupid? Perhaps, there some points I don't know ...

Comment: Not just _want_. The continuous construction is usable whenever a reasonable continuity can be posited. A very common topic introduction phrase goes _I've been wanting/meaning/intending to tell/ask/warn you `S`_; it means that for some time I have been experiencing a desire or intention, and this is the first opportunity to satisfy it (so please cooperate). Since desire and many other erstwhile stative predicates are mental or emotional experiences, knowledge of continuing experiences can constitute a domain for the continuous construction.

Comment: @JohnLawler, forgive my ignorance. So, as I understand we can use it like in your example above, only when we have something   `it means that for some time I have been experiencing a desire or intention, and this is the first opportunity to satisfy it (so please cooperate). ince desire and many other erstwhile stative predicates are mental or emotional experiences, knowledge of continuing experiences can constitute a domain for the continuous construction.`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We'd been wanting to go to New Zealand for years, so sixtieth birthday was a good excuse.

This a correct, as the continuing action is explicit in "for years".  It suggests the "wanting" is past and over.

> We wanted to go to New Zealand for years, so sixtieth birthday was a good excuse

This is also correct.  It suggests both "wanted to go" and "sixtieth birthday" have past.

> We're wanting to buy a new TV, but we are not sure what to get

This is grammatically correct, but suggests that the prospect of  "buying" is immediate. The *continuous* (or *progressive*) construction suggests the action of "wanting to buy"  is "right now".

> We want to buy a new TV, but we are not sure what to get

This is also correct. What is called the *(simple) present tense* suggests only that the action is current, and has no definite beginning or end.

.