# I have been wanting to meet you for a long time

Tags: verbs

I have seen the sentence in a book prepared by a reputed English institute in India. I know that words like 'want'  and 'need' do not take the progressive form.
 Is it possible to use want in the progressive form in an informal speech?

I would like you to respond to my question because most of the users on our site are also using 'need' and 'want' in the progressive form and the sentences are not being edited.

Comment: Related: [“Wanting” or “want”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110817/wanting-or-want) and [What's the difference between “I want” and “I am wanting”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36597/whats-the-difference-between-i-want-and-i-am-wanting) and [Using stative verb “want” in progressive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368416/using-stative-verb-want-in-progressive)

Comment: [“I'm lovin' it”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/im-lovin-it) Dated Dec 10 '10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: want and need are **state**, **non-continuous** or **stative verbs**, and aren't used in continuous tenses.

https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/stative-verbs.html

However, they are widely used in continuous (progressive) forms in informal speech. I blame McDonald's for their "I'm lovin' it" slogan. It may also be more prevalent in Indian English (Chandrika Balasubramanian, *[Register Variation in Indian English](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RB04Ay545rwC&dq)*,
Volume 37 of Studies in corpus linguistics, 4.2.1 p.90).

Comment: "I have been wanting to do [something] for a long time" is perfectly idiomatic English.

Comment: I disagree with a lot of that first list in thinking they cannot be used in continuous tenses.

Comment: l am thiking of going to kashmir is ok but can we say that I am thinking you are right?

Comment: ..and aren't **normally** used in continuous tenses.