# Is "understand" also a dynamic verb

Tags: semantics, stative-verbs, dynamic-verbs

It is well known that *understand* is a stative verb. But it can also mean "in the process of understanding". So "I am understanding it" sound ok, which suggests that *understand* is dynamic as well. Any idea on this?

Comment: It's often possible to use the progressive form of stative words when you want to emphasise that something is currently going on and is relevant to the present situation, e.g. "I'm understanding what you are saying, but I don't think it's a good idea" to emphasise that you genuinely are aware of what they're saying and are actively considering it. See e.g.  ["I'm wanting..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368416/using-stative-verb-want-in-progressive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think Understand is  an **action  verb.**  understand  is  not used  in the  progressive   forms   according to many  standard  grammar  books

**I am understanding**  is ungrammatical and  it  is   not idiomatic   and  is  rarely  used  by  native  speakers.
It is correct and idiomatic to say :    **I am beginning  to understand**  ,  if you are in the process of  understanding.

We usually  say **I understand** , **I have understood.**

> **I have been  understanding**  is  rarely  used  by  native  speakers

Here is   a   link  which  shows  the  usage   of  **Understand**

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/understand

Comment: You either understand something or you don't. If you want to express that it is a gradual process you would have to say something like "I am beginning to understand".

Comment: I'll throw in that it's possible to use "I am understanding" as a linking verb construction, using the adjective form of understanding which means "sympathetically aware of other people's feelings; tolerant and forgiving." Ex. "She was very understanding of my situation, but nevertheless she couldn't hire me."

Comment: Using  ing form as an adjective, gerund  does not   come  under  progressive  forms.

Comment: I know that. The OP said "I am understanding" is ungrammatical and unidiomatic. I was giving an example in which the same words are used (albeit with different functions) and it works just fine.

Comment: In "I am understanding", I mean the progressive aspect, not gerund or adjective.

Comment: I am understanding  is not  advisable.we understand or  do not  understand  as we know  and do not know.

Comment: The down voter should show me the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If I say, "I understand your language", is that not grammatical, and is not "language" the direct object? If it is grammatical then, "I am understanding your language" should be just fine.

Comment: Native English speakers only very rarely use continuous tenses for stative verbs. So *I am understanding your language*, while completely comprehensible, would not be used outside of exceptional circumstances.